# Esper expression in another epl file

Tags: java, esper, complex-event-processing

How to distribute **expressions** in other EPL files?

I tried but there are two problems need to see.

1. Any EPL file cannot contain only 'Expression'.('Unexpected end' error)
2. Accessing expression defined in another EPL file, gives 'not found' error.

Here is my attempt: 
//epl1.epl

```
module eplTest;
expression twoPI 
{ 
  3.141 * 2
}
```

//epl2.epl

```
module eplTestmain;
uses SampleEvent;
uses eplTest;

select twoPI() from SampleEvent;
```

I am using netbeans.

It will be also useful if I get **how to create single row function in epl?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no "create expression" syntax in Esper EPL currently, expressions are statement-local and not currently globabaly declarable

Comment: Thanks, Any other way to organize common formulae? I don't want to use java classes for this.

Comment: Could you please also look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595930/esper-window-uses-recalculation-based-on-event-leaving-window

Comment: I am novice in CEP field. So please view my other Esper question and help me out if you can.