# Esper window usage: Recalculation based on event leaving window

Tags: java, esper, complex-event-processing

I need somewhat like this.

```
//Create a named window (w1)
Create window w1....

//then insert events into window
insert into w1....
select amount,.....
from....
where...

//remove from window
on RemoveEventArrived as r
Delete from w1
where w1.id = r.id
```

Now insert into another event from w1 named window

```
//inserting into final output event
insert into derivedevent
select sum(w.amount)
from w1 as w

suppose event sequence:
1. Event with id=1 and amount= 100 arrived.
   o/p of sum(amount) triggered and gives 100.

2. Event withid = 2 and amount=200 arrived.
  o/p of sum(amount) triggered and gives 300.

3. **Remove** Event with id=1 arrived.
o/p of sum(amount) triggered and gives 200.

4. Event with id = 3 and amount=500 arrived
o/p of sum(amount) triggered and gives  700
```

but somewhat 3rd event could not trigger derivedevent recalculatin automatically.
While arrival of 4th event triggers and gives output as required.

Any standard way of doing it?

**I want to calculate sum of amount whether a new event arrive into window or leaving it.**

Answer (score 1):

The 3. event (remove) does trigger output of a new sum by "insert into derivedevent", unless nothing was removed, therefore perhaps your id keys are wrong.
Send a minimal test case to the esper user mailing list if still having trouble.
Or use @Audit to see what the engine does internally for each statement.

Comment: I have updated question please look into it. Specially 4th event gives o/p as required.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. If you found a solution and didn't post it yet, please share. Thanks